# Value of the limit without (or with, but giving rigorous arguments) using the Taylor expansion of sin

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to evaluate the limit as $N\to \infty.$

$$\frac{  \left(\dfrac{\sin \frac{1}{N}} {\frac{1}{N}}\right)^{N}   -1 }{\frac{1}{N}}.$$

Note first that, using L'Hôpital, one can easily show that the numerator goes to $0.$

Using the Taylor series expansion for $sin$, the value of the actual limit seems to be  $-\frac{1}{6}$. But I'm not fully sure how to justify the infinite series in the numerator is $-\frac{1}{6N}+O(\frac{1}{N^2})$. You could either justify that, if I was right, or may be use some other method to tell me what the limit is?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't stated in the problem what value $N$ approaches.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about that. I added that part now.

Answer (score 1):

Just develop carefully the Taylor expansion.

$$\sin \frac{1}{N}=\frac{1}{N}-\frac{1}{6N^3}+O(\frac{1}{N^5})$$

Then

$$\left(\frac{\sin \frac{1}{N}}{\frac{1}{N}}\right)^N=\exp \left[N \log\left( 1-\frac{1}{6N^2}+O(\frac{1}{N^4})\right)\right]=\exp\left[N\left(-\frac{1}{6N^2}+O(\frac{1}{N^4})\right)\right]=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{6N}+O(\frac{1}{N^3})\right)=1-\frac{1}{6N}+O(\frac{1}{N^2})$$

And

$$\frac{\left(\frac{\sin \frac{1}{N}}{\frac{1}{N}}\right)^N-1}{\frac{1}{N}}
=N\left(-\frac{1}{6N}+O(\frac{1}{N^2})\right)=-\frac{1}{6}+O(\frac{1}{N})$$

Hence the limit as $N\to\infty$ is $-\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: @Jean-Clause: thanks. I think my problem is only with the first line. Could you explicitly prove the Taylor expansion. I do believe it, but I need a rigorous proof. Thanks again!

Comment: @Mathmath This is rigorous. The only thing you have to know is the composition of Taylor expansions: if $f$ has a Taylor expansion at order $n$ at $x_0$, $P_n(x)+O((x-x_0)^n)$ and $g$ has T.E. at order $n$ at $x_1=f(x_0)$, $Q_n(x)+O((x-x_1)^n)$, then $g\circ f$ has a T.E. at order $n$, $Q_n\circ P_n(x)+O((x-x_0)^n$. Apply this to the log and then the exponential, and you are done. Of course, when computiong the composition of polynomials, don't forget that all terms of order $\geq n$ disappear in the $O((x-x_0)^n)$.